# moment.js isoWeek does not work on Heroku instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, momentjs

My app depends on `moment().startOf('isoWeek')` in order to determine the current start of the week. On my machine, this works fine and returns `Mon Oct 31 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)` as expected. However, on my Heroku instance, this code breaks server side, returning `Sun Oct 30 2016 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)`. These outputs are gathered from just running `console.log(moment().startOf('isoWeek'))` in an Express endpoint.

The code also works as expected on the client side on my deployed Heroku application, returning Monday when I log it, it only seems to give the wrong output on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the Heroku instance default timezone is UTC and your local machine will have your timezone.

Are you running this server-side (on node.js)? Or are you running this client-side? If you run it client-side it should detect your timezone.